# Trying to connect to emulator with appium. getting "Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4723"

Tags: android, appium

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
public class AutomateCalci2 {
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad; AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad;
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    
            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5556");
            dc.setCapability("PlatformName", "android");
            dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
            dc.setCapability("appActivity", ".Calculator");
    
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
            ad = new AndroidDriver<>(url, dc);
        }
}
```

```
Error :   

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:4723
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i686', os.version: '5.4.61-android11-0-00791-gbad091cc4bf3-ab6833933', java.version: '0'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at
```

io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:338)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:89)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:99)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:96)
at com.example.demo.AutomateCalci2.setUp(AutomateCalci2.java:32)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:76)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2205)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:193)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:4723
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$1(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.-$$Lambda$AppiumCommandExecutor$ugxFyNh-3C39Ft1S_xMmdYNBRGY.execute(Unknown Source:2)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 4723) from /127.0.0.1 (port 37078) after 120000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:287)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:192)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:134)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
... 65 more
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:274)
... 75 more

```
Tests ran to completion.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add automationName and version capability in the capabilities as :

   dc.setCapability("automationName","UIAutomator2");

   dc.setCapability("version","10");

   [whichever version, your emulator is running]
2. Try invoking appium as administrator or using command line.